# Enumeration methods

Tags: java

Enumeration interface has method hashMoreElements is used with refrence variable (Enumv), how can they be used
since they are not implemented ?
I meant it is an interface method so how can it be called - Enumv.hasMoreElements() it does not have a implementation .

```
Vector v = new Vector();
//v contains list of elements - Suppose
Enumeration Enumv = v.elements();
while(Enumv.hasMoreElements()) {
    System.out.println(Enumv.nextElement());
}
```

How is this possible?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Please revise the terminology you used.

Comment: @close-voters: How 'bout giving the guy a couple of minutes to fix it? (Yes, he should have been clearer originally, but...)

Comment: I apologize for the same , I actually tried using code tag but didnt work that time .

Comment: @Pratik: Somewhat off-topic but: Look at [`Iterator`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) instead of `Enumeration` if you have a choice. `Enumeration` is the older interface, `Iterator` is now preferred.

Comment: @Pratik: I don't think it's the code that's the problem. We don't understand what you're trying to ask.

Comment: Can you enumerate the reasons why it's not possible, as Enumeration acts in fact as ResultSet in JDBC or Iterator : by providing a view over an iteration.

Comment: @Patrik: Formatting rules are explained in right hand column while you're in the message editor. The message editor has buttons in toolbar. They have all tooltips. The message editor has a preview area at the bottom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your code,

```
Enumeration Enumv = v.elements();
```

This is what `Vector` is returning to you.

```
public Enumeration<E> elements() {
    return new Enumeration<E>() {
        int count = 0;

        public boolean hasMoreElements() {
        return count < elementCount;
        }

        public E nextElement() {
        synchronized (Vector.this) {
            if (count < elementCount) {
            return (E)elementData[count++];
            }
        }
        throw new NoSuchElementException("Vector Enumeration");
        }
    };
}
```

As you can see, Vector returns an implemented `Enumeration` class (which annonymous to the developer).

> **so how can it be called - Enumv.hasMoreElements() it does not
>   have a implementation .**

It is implemented (as shown above).

Answer (score 3):

`Enumeration` is an interface. It provides the method definitions, but anything implementing the interface has to provide the implementation. The point is that code *using* the object via the interface doesn't need to know about the implementation - just that *something* is implementing the relevant methods.

In the case of the value returned by `Vector.elements()`, the `Enumeration` implementation is actually provided via an anonymous inner class - but the caller doesn't need to care about that at all.

(Note that this isn't specific to `Enumeration` - it's the general principle of interfaces.)

Comment: I didnt get the Anonymous inner class stuff Can you please simplify it for me

Comment: @Patrik: download JDK, integrate `src.zip` in your IDE -if any- and read the source code while opening `java.util.Vector` class. The implementation is there in `elements()` method.

Comment: @Pratik: It sounds like you could do with reading a good Java book, to be honest. Stack Overflow is great for specific questions, but it's not a good way of learning a language.

Comment: I am learning it from complete reference - Herbert Schdilt , and yup its quite difficult to figure out everything.

Comment: @Pratik: In general, I'd avoid trying to *learn* something from a *reference*. Reference books are generally there to look up specific things, rather than acting as tutorials.

Comment: @Pratik One more note: get a newer book, Vector and Enumeration are out of Date. How about reading "Java generics and Collections" http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596527754 or the Sun Tutorial Collections Trail http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections

Answer (score 1):

`Vector.elements()` doesn't simply return "an enumeration".
In reallity it returns an instance of an implementation of `Enumeration` but an implementation of `Enumeration` "is-a" `Enumeration` and can be "casted" to `Enumeration` interface.

So the method is implemented, that's why it works.

---

In the `Vector` case the implementation is an anonymous class directly based on `Enumeration`.

```
public Enumeration<E> elements() {
    return new Enumeration<E>() {
        int count = 0;

        public boolean hasMoreElements() {
            return count < elementCount;
        }

        public E nextElement() {
            synchronized (Vector.this) {
                if (count < elementCount) {
                    return elementData(count++);
                }
            }
            throw new NoSuchElementException("Vector Enumeration");
        }
    };
}
```

---

**Resources :**

- [grepcode - `Vector.elements()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Vector.java#Vector.elements%28%29)

Comment: It returns an instance of enumeration but there is no class of Enumeration . I didnt get it

Comment: There is implementations of Enumeration. For instance the one returned by `v.elements();`. You can't have instance of interfaces, each instance is linked to a class.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your question completely.

The class Vector has an implementation of the elements() method, that returns an Enumeration.  The concrete implementation of Enumeration that is returned is required to have an implementation of the hasMoreElements() method.

Answer (score 0):

The `elements()` method of the `Vector` class returns an instance of an anonymous class that implements the methods of the `Enumeration` interface. You don't need to know anything about this class, since the interface defines how it should behave - that's exactly the point of interfaces.

Note that `Vector` and `Enumeration` are both obsolete and should not be used anymore. Instead, use `ArrayList` and `Iterator`.